# ORA-22992 view in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Hello friends I have a detail when creating a view in oracle because I use the ROW_NUMBER to count the elements of my query, however when creating the view I get the following error

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

The query I run is as follows

```
SELECT TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_ID AS ID_TEMPLATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By SIGNERS.DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID Order By SIGNERS.DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID DESC )  AS ID_SIGN

FROM TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT@BDLINK  TEMPLATE 
INNER JOIN DOMAIN_TEMPLATE_CATALOG@BDLINK DOMAIN 
ON TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_ID = DOMAIN.DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID
INNER JOIN SIGNERS_DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE@WBDLINK  SIGNERS
ON DOMAIN.DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID = SIGNERS.DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID

AND TEMPLATE.ESTATUS = 1;
```

I am making a view with a dblink to be able to access some data and tables that correspond to another bd, the SIGNERS table has a column of type lob.

Is there any way to solve this issue since I am not querying the column of this type in the over partition ?

the results I get from my query are currently correct

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it friends if anyone encounters something similar in the following post explain why and the solution https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-22992-no-lob-field-selected